# Unable to execute functions from external scripts in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm trying to implement the Jquery plugin called Cropper in a Meteor project I'm working on and it's giving me some confusing results.

Thusfar I've imported cropper as an npm through the command line and then used a method from within cropper to set up the image in question for cropping and that has worked fine.
However when I attach a cropper function to a button within the same template I'm getting an error of "cropper not defined" in the console.

My code thusfar looks like this:
Client/main.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Testing Cropper</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div>
        {{> StudentImageDisplay}}
    </div>
</body>

<template name="StudentImageDisplay">
    Click and drag a box to select the portion of the image you would like to use.<br>
    Double click image to shift between selection box and image draggning<br>
    Click the Save button below to save to database. <br>
    <div class="StudentImage">
        <img src="/Science.jpg" alt="studentimage">
    </div>
    <div>   
        <button class="CropImage">Crop</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

main.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

Template.StudentImageDisplay.onRendered(function () {
    $('.StudentImage > img').cropper({
        aspectRatio: 0.75,
        autoCropArea: 0.65,
        strict: false,
        guides: false,
        highlight: false,
        dragCrop: false,
        cropBoxMovable: false,
        cropBoxResizable: false
    });
});

Template.StudentImageDisplay.events({
   'click .CropImage': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
    console.log("Cropped image to Canvas for realsies");
   }
});
```

The problem arises in that cropper.getCroppedCanvas() call near the bottom, as it just throws an error of "Uncaught Exception: cropper is not defined".

I think I'm missing something really basic here, like that it's not been imported properly or it's outside of scope but I've been fiddling with it for about an hour now and can't decipher the example code well enough to find my problem. If anyone could tell me what I'm missing here that would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
$().cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
```

I assume this is the plugin you use: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper

Comment: That worked! Thanks man, I knew it had to be something simple I was missing.